# Is the <guide> still needed in ePub 3?

Tags: epub, opf, guide

Suprised I haven't found this when searching the site under the parameters `<guide>` and when searching IDPF documentation for ePub 3 spec I didn't see an answer.  I was curious what does the `<guide>` do at the end of the OPF file in an ePub 3?  I did read the write up "[Where do you start an ePUB and what is the  section of the .OPF file?](http://epubsecrets.com/where-do-you-start-an-epub-and-what-is-the-guide-section-of-the-opf-file.php)" but this was published back in 2011 when ePub 2 was still common:

> “The guide element identifies fundamental structural components of
>   the publication, to enable Reading Systems to provide convenient
>   access to them.” So how does the  work? Essentially, it points
>   to where particular pieces of the book can be found, allowing reading
>   systems to go directly to that file or location.

For example:

```
    <guide>
        <reference href="foo.xhtml" type="cover" title="Cover"/>
        <reference href="bar.xhtml" type="text" title="Start"/>
    </guide>
</package>
```

I know traditionally ePub2 used the `<guide>` often and per Apple documentation I use `<guide>` in fixed layout but other then that is there still a need for the `<guide>` or is it only for legacy devices and reading engines?

Answer (score 1):

It's now deprecated in epub3 in favor of the landmark NAV element. 
http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#sec-guide-elem

Because support for NAV is pretty much universal in reading systems, I see no reason why to include it now.